# Polynomial Manipulation Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Recently I have been working on a QR code project and have been working on polynomial manipulation for Error Correction

The Directions and example are shown below:
[image]

While these directions can be done on paper I find it hard and challenging to program.
To help with this I am using the Sympy Library for polynomial manipulation but I am having some problems,
Currently, My code has me down to the step where I need to take the `a` variable and transform it into galios field, however, I am having a hard time actually grabbing the certain sections of the polynomial and grabbing the LC and/or the Exponent to do Exponent Addition. I will link my code below any help would be grateful.

```py
import sympy as s
a, x = s.symbols('a,x')

def polynomial_generator(value, steps, step):
    step += 1
    step_polynomial = (x + a ** step)

    # Multiply Terms out & Combined Terms
    value = value * step_polynomial

    # GF Addition -Unsure how to grab the Exponent/LC
    
    # XOR
    # Result

    if step == steps - 1:
        return value
    else:
        polynomial_generator(value, steps, step)


ec_generation = 2
first_value = (x + a**0).as_poly()

polynomial = polynomial_generator(first_value, ec_generation,0)
# https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-coding
```

My Code will return a Polynomial Type as the following:

```py
Poly(x**2 + (a + 1)*x + a, x, domain='ZZ[a]')
```

I am also interested in a way to stop Sympy from transferring `a^0` to `1` just for the nature of the problem and dealing with antilog and XOR conversion with the alpha notation

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to keep `a^0` since poly always seems to simplify the expression. I even tried using a custom class that inherits from `Symbol` but to no avail. SymPy also seems a fairly bad choice for this highly numeric calculation. A computer algebra system should not be needed when you could simply create a function that takes 2 list representing polynomials and multiplies them.

Here's what was working for me but I'm sure just hardcoding it yourself will be faster and less finicky.

```py
from sympy import *

alpha_to_int = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 8, 4: 16, 5: 32, 6: 64, 7: 128, 8: 29, 9: 58, 10: 116, 11: 232, 12: 205, 13: 135, 14: 19, 15: 38, 16: 76, 17: 152, 18: 45, 19: 90, 20: 180, 21: 117, 22: 234, 23: 201, 24: 143, 25: 3, 26: 6, 27: 12, 28: 24, 29: 48, 30: 96, 31: 192, 32: 157, 33: 39, 34: 78, 35: 156, 36: 37, 37: 74, 38: 148, 39: 53, 40: 106, 41: 212, 42: 181, 43: 119, 44: 238, 45: 193, 46: 159, 47: 35, 48: 70, 49: 140, 50: 5, 51: 10, 52: 20, 53: 40, 54: 80, 55: 160, 56: 93, 57: 186, 58: 105, 59: 210, 60: 185, 61: 111, 62: 222, 63: 161, 64: 95, 65: 190, 66: 97, 67: 194, 68: 153, 69: 47, 70: 94, 71: 188, 72: 101, 73: 202, 74: 137, 75: 15, 76: 30, 77: 60, 78: 120, 79: 240, 80: 253, 81: 231, 82: 211, 83: 187, 84: 107, 85: 214, 86: 177, 87: 127, 88: 254, 89: 225, 90: 223, 91: 163, 92: 91, 93: 182, 94: 113, 95: 226, 96: 217, 97: 175, 98: 67, 99: 134, 100: 17, 101: 34, 102: 68, 103: 136, 104: 13, 105: 26, 106: 52, 107: 104, 108: 208, 109: 189, 110: 103, 111: 206, 112: 129, 113: 31, 114: 62, 115: 124, 116: 248, 117: 237, 118: 199, 119: 147, 120: 59, 121: 118, 122: 236, 123: 197, 124: 151, 125: 51, 126: 102, 127: 204, 128: 133, 129: 23, 130: 46, 131: 92, 132: 184, 133: 109, 134: 218, 135: 169, 136: 79, 137: 158, 138: 33, 139: 66, 140: 132, 141: 21, 142: 42, 143: 84, 144: 168, 145: 77, 146: 154, 147: 41, 148: 82, 149: 164, 150: 85, 151: 170, 152: 73, 153: 146, 154: 57, 155: 114, 156: 228, 157: 213, 158: 183, 159: 115, 160: 230, 161: 209, 162: 191, 163: 99, 164: 198, 165: 145, 166: 63, 167: 126, 168: 252, 169: 229, 170: 215, 171: 179, 172: 123, 173: 246, 174: 241, 175: 255, 176: 227, 177: 219, 178: 171, 179: 75, 180: 150, 181: 49, 182: 98, 183: 196, 184: 149, 185: 55, 186: 110, 187: 220, 188: 165, 189: 87, 190: 174, 191: 65, 192: 130, 193: 25, 194: 50, 195: 100, 196: 200, 197: 141, 198: 7, 199: 14, 200: 28, 201: 56, 202: 112, 203: 224, 204: 221, 205: 167, 206: 83, 207: 166, 208: 81, 209: 162, 210: 89, 211: 178, 212: 121, 213: 242, 214: 249, 215: 239, 216: 195, 217: 155, 218: 43, 219: 86, 220: 172, 221: 69, 222: 138, 223: 9, 224: 18, 225: 36, 226: 72, 227: 144, 228: 61, 229: 122, 230: 244, 231: 245, 232: 247, 233: 243, 234: 251, 235: 235, 236: 203, 237: 139, 238: 11, 239: 22, 240: 44, 241: 88, 242: 176, 243: 125, 244: 250, 245: 233, 246: 207, 247: 131, 248: 27, 249: 54, 250: 108, 251: 216, 252: 173, 253: 71, 254: 142, 255: 1}
int_to_alpha = {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 25, 4: 2, 5: 50, 6: 26, 7: 198, 8: 3, 9: 223, 10: 51, 11: 238, 12: 27, 13: 104, 14: 199, 15: 75, 16: 4, 17: 100, 18: 224, 19: 14, 20: 52, 21: 141, 22: 239, 23: 129, 24: 28, 25: 193, 26: 105, 27: 248, 28: 200, 29: 8, 30: 76, 31: 113, 32: 5, 33: 138, 34: 101, 35: 47, 36: 225, 37: 36, 38: 15, 39: 33, 40: 53, 41: 147, 42: 142, 43: 218, 44: 240, 45: 18, 46: 130, 47: 69, 48: 29, 49: 181, 50: 194, 51: 125, 52: 106, 53: 39, 54: 249, 55: 185, 56: 201, 57: 154, 58: 9, 59: 120, 60: 77, 61: 228, 62: 114, 63: 166, 64: 6, 65: 191, 66: 139, 67: 98, 68: 102, 69: 221, 70: 48, 71: 253, 72: 226, 73: 152, 74: 37, 75: 179, 76: 16, 77: 145, 78: 34, 79: 136, 80: 54, 81: 208, 82: 148, 83: 206, 84: 143, 85: 150, 86: 219, 87: 189, 88: 241, 89: 210, 90: 19, 91: 92, 92: 131, 93: 56, 94: 70, 95: 64, 96: 30, 97: 66, 98: 182, 99: 163, 100: 195, 101: 72, 102: 126, 103: 110, 104: 107, 105: 58, 106: 40, 107: 84, 108: 250, 109: 133, 110: 186, 111: 61, 112: 202, 113: 94, 114: 155, 115: 159, 116: 10, 117: 21, 118: 121, 119: 43, 120: 78, 121: 212, 122: 229, 123: 172, 124: 115, 125: 243, 126: 167, 127: 87, 128: 7, 129: 112, 130: 192, 131: 247, 132: 140, 133: 128, 134: 99, 135: 13, 136: 103, 137: 74, 138: 222, 139: 237, 140: 49, 141: 197, 142: 254, 143: 24, 144: 227, 145: 165, 146: 153, 147: 119, 148: 38, 149: 184, 150: 180, 151: 124, 152: 17, 153: 68, 154: 146, 155: 217, 156: 35, 157: 32, 158: 137, 159: 46, 160: 55, 161: 63, 162: 209, 163: 91, 164: 149, 165: 188, 166: 207, 167: 205, 168: 144, 169: 135, 170: 151, 171: 178, 172: 220, 173: 252, 174: 190, 175: 97, 176: 242, 177: 86, 178: 211, 179: 171, 180: 20, 181: 42, 182: 93, 183: 158, 184: 132, 185: 60, 186: 57, 187: 83, 188: 71, 189: 109, 190: 65, 191: 162, 192: 31, 193: 45, 194: 67, 195: 216, 196: 183, 197: 123, 198: 164, 199: 118, 200: 196, 201: 23, 202: 73, 203: 236, 204: 127, 205: 12, 206: 111, 207: 246, 208: 108, 209: 161, 210: 59, 211: 82, 212: 41, 213: 157, 214: 85, 215: 170, 216: 251, 217: 96, 218: 134, 219: 177, 220: 187, 221: 204, 222: 62, 223: 90, 224: 203, 225: 89, 226: 95, 227: 176, 228: 156, 229: 169, 230: 160, 231: 81, 232: 11, 233: 245, 234: 22, 235: 235, 236: 122, 237: 117, 238: 44, 239: 215, 240: 79, 241: 174, 242: 213, 243: 233, 244: 230, 245: 231, 246: 173, 247: 232, 248: 116, 249: 214, 250: 244, 251: 234, 252: 168, 253: 80, 254: 88, 255: 175}
# out of curiosity, why doesn't 0 map to 255 in int_to_alpha?
# Even then it wouldn't be a bijection. Very weird that both 0 and 255 map to 1 in int_to_alpha

# Xor in sympy is for logic not for integers
def xor_numeric(a, b):
    return S(int(a) ^ int(b))
xor_symbolic = Function('xor')
a, x = symbols('a x')


def polynomial_generator(value, steps, step):
    step += 1
    step_polynomial = (x + a ** step)

    # Multiply Terms out & Combined Terms
    value: Poly = value * step_polynomial

    # GF Addition -Unsure how to grab the Exponent/LC
    coeffs = value.coeffs()

    # change + to XOR before substitution otherwise sympy will simplify the addition
    coeffs = [coeff.replace(Add, xor_symbolic) for coeff in coeffs]

    # convert a**k to an integer
    coeffs = [coeff.xreplace({a ** k: v for k, v in alpha_to_int.items()})
              if isinstance(coeff, Add) else coeff.replace(a, alpha_to_int[1])
              for coeff in coeffs]

    # evaluate the expression with the numeric xor
    coeffs = [coeff.replace(xor_symbolic, xor_numeric) for coeff in coeffs]

    # convert the integers back to a**k
    coeffs = [coeff.xreplace({k: Pow(a, k, evaluate=False) for k, v in int_to_alpha.items()})
              for coeff in coeffs]

    # Result
    value = Poly(coeffs, x)

    if step == steps - 1:
        return value
    else:
        polynomial_generator(value, steps, step)


ec_generation = 2

first_value = (x + a ** 0).as_poly(x)  # poly in x
polynomial = polynomial_generator(first_value, ec_generation, 0)
print(polynomial)
```

Which gives `Poly(x**2 + a**25*x + a, x, domain='ZZ[a]')`.

You could do the above all in one go without recursion using

```py
values = [(x + a ** step) for step in range(ec_generation)]
polynomial = prod(values).as_poly(x, auto=False)
```

and then inserting the `coeffs = ...` lines below that. Again, coding the polynomial multiplication from scratch would probably lead to more efficient code.